# What are mixers that balance multiple inputs and outputs called?

Tags: hardware

Im looking for a mixer that allow me to balance 2 input for 2 distinct outputs. What are these mixers called?

Comment: Unbalanced to balanced converter http://www.parts-express.com/art-cleanboxpro-stereo-balanced-unbalanced-converter--245-868 for 2 channels

Comment: oh, that kind of balance... I read as 'volume change' kind of balance.

Comment: @Tetsujin Actually it IS volume control :P I have input from computer and mic and I want to mix it to 2 different outputs

Comment: My bad then? Sorry i dont quite get what's the question :o

Comment: I have 2 input that I want to mix into 2 output each with different configuration. I'm not quite sure what to look for when searching the internet

Comment: sounds to me just like a 'mixer', though your request still isn't clear. Anyway, this question really has nothing to do with sound design, it's a hardware shopping request

Comment: Are you asking about 
1. "mixers" that do not mix, but only adjust the volume of signals separately and isolated.
2."mixers" that may create several different mixes of various signals (I.e. mix1 = mic + a little computer, mix2 = alot of computer and a little mic)
3. "mixers" that will create balanced signals from unbalanced signals (thats rather technical and has nothing to do with volume).

Comment: @Michael I would be looking for 2. I'm not very technical about these stuff and might not be getting the names right. I'm looking for the technical name such that I can search online for it.

Comment: What kind of inputs, microphone, guitar, line? Sounds like a stereo preamp with output level control is what you need, which isn't a mixer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at "Zone Mixers" or "Matrix Mixers".

[image]

An example would be [here](https://www.thomann.de/ie/swissonic_zm_4.htm)
(this is just an example, I have no affiliation with website nor product)

One thing to keep in mind with such equipment is that inputs, as well as outputs, are usually single (mono) channels, and therefore you need to use 2 inputs, and 2 outputs if you desire stereo.

HTH,
Edwin.